# TypeError: can't concat NoneType to bytes

Tags: python, flask, yolo

I am using flask for creating api and then serving it on aws. I've created a lambda function for triggering the url, which is sent dynamically from IOT device. However my frame is stopped after sometime around 10 seconds, and throwing an error
`TypeError: can't concat NoneType to bytes`

```
@app.route('/<id>')
def yolo_v4(id):
    try:
        kinesis1 = vid_stream.get_hls_url(id)
        cap =  cv2.VideoCapture(kinesis1)
        
        # success,image = self.gen_frames("ucCPm3MMSbPmzxWcvd1zb5").read()
    
        previous = time()
        yolo_v4.delta = 0
        while True:
            success,image = cap.read()
            current = time()

            yolo_v4.delta += current - previous
            previous = current
            frame = image
            # frame = camera.do_something()
            # detection(frame, 0.5)

            try:
                create_alert(frame)

            except Exception as e:
                print("Exception after create alert function:",e)

            if not success:
                break
            
            else:

                ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
                frame = jpeg.tobytes()
                
                pass
                
                    
    except Exception as e:
        pass

    # yield (b'--frame\r\n'
    #     b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')

    yield b'--frame\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n'
    yield frame
    yield b'\r\n\r\n'
```

I don't want to show the video anywhere that's why I even tried removing yield, when removing yield it throws another error
`"The function either returned None or ended without a return statement"`

Lambda code for triggering

```
import json
import logging
import urllib3



logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


# --- Main handler ---

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    """
    Route the incoming request based on intent.
    The JSON body of the request is provided in the event slot.
    """
   
    print("PPE Event",event)
    streamName = event['deviceId']
    print("StreamName",streamName)
    
    http = urllib3.PoolManager()
    logger.debug("test")
    
    response = http.request("GET", "http://ec2-102.somenumber.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/"+streamName)
    print(response.status)
    return response
```